# How to give some condition to elastics search query

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have a NodeJS application which is using mongoosastic api for Elasticsearch. Now I need a way of adding a condition(isDeleted == false) to the specified query(query: req.query.q).

this is my code

```
exports.search = function (req, res) {
  if (!req.query.q) return res.status(400).send('No Query Provided')
  log.error(req.query.q)
  User.search({query_string: {query: req.query.q}}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return handleError(res, err)
    var ret = _.map(results.hits.hits, result => ({
      userID: result._id,
      _score: result._score,
      name: result._source.name,
      loc: result._source.loc,
      info: result._source.info,
      images: result._source.images
    }))
    return res.send(ret)
  })
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filtering to filter your data. Check the [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic#indexing-a-geo-shape) of your plugin website. Following example is your answer also.

```
var geoQuery = {query_string: {query: req.query.q}};

var myFilter = {
  term: {
    isDeleted: true
  }
};

User.search(geoQuery, {filter: myFilter}, function(err, res) { /* ... */ })
```

Comment: Sorry but it did not help

Comment: Why did not it help?

Comment: I did how you said,  but again when searching deleted user, it finds and displays

Comment: var geoQuery = {query_string: {query: req.query.q}};
  var myFilter = {
    terms: {
      isDeleted: true
    }
  };

  User.search(geoQuery, {filter: myFilter}, (err, results) => {

Comment: if (err) return handleError(res, err)
    var ret = _.map(results.hits.hits, result => ({
      userID: result._id,
      _score: result._score,
      name: result._source.name,
      loc: result._source.loc,
      info: result._source.info,
      images: result._source.images
    }))
    return res.send(ret)
  })
}

Comment: What is your es version?

Comment: And what is your plugin version?

Comment: "mongoosastic": "^4.0.2",   this is my elastics version....and about plugin version I do not understund what plugin are you speaking about.